# SetError produces exception with custom style in TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-styles, android-textinputlayout

I'm using an Edittext inside of a TextInputLayout using a custom style so that I can change the hint color. If I use the EditText without setting the style, the `setError` method works fine, but with my style set the next exception is thrown:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24: TypedValue{t=0x3/d=0x2b5 "res/color/secondary_text_material_dark.xml" a=1 r=0x1060166}
                                                                             at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:447)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:745)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:678)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:674)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:670)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(TextInputLayout.java:380)
                                                                             at android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.setError(TextInputLayout.java:425)
                                                                             at com.wallakoala.wallakoala.Activities.SignUpUI.validateEmail(SignUpUI.java:50)
                                                                             at com.wallakoala.wallakoala.Activities.SignUpUI.access$100(SignUpUI.java:21)
                                                                             at com.wallakoala.wallakoala.Activities.SignUpUI$MyTextWatcher.afterTextChanged(SignUpUI.java:103)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView.sendAfterTextChanged(TextView.java:8017)
                                                                             at android.widget.TextView$ChangeWatcher.afterTextChanged(TextView.java:10182)
                                                                             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.sendAfterTextChanged(SpannableStringBuilder.java:1043)
                                                                             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:560)
                                                                             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:492)
                                                                             at android.text.SpannableStringBuilder.replace(SpannableStringBuilder.java:34)
                                                                             at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.replaceText(BaseInputConnection.java:685)
                                                                             at android.view.inputmethod.BaseInputConnection.setComposingText(BaseInputConnection.java:445)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:340)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
                                                                             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
                                                                             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                                                                             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

This is the XML of the EditText

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="34dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="34dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:theme="@style/TextLabel">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/email_edittext"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@color/colorText"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorMediumText"
            android:hint="@string/email_hint"
            android:nextFocusUp="@id/email_edittext"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/email_edittext"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

This is the style defined in styles.xml.

```
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/colorLightText</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14dp</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorMediumText</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

And this is the line that produces the error:

```
emailInputLayout.setError("Incorrect email");
```

Any idea of what's happening?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: You can't set the hint color programmatically?

Comment: Nop, it does nothing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the error, these attributes have to be in the style:

```
<item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/COLOR</item>
<item name="android:textColorLink">@color/COLOR</item>
```

Comment: Thanks i am at the same xml